# Как загрузить файл на dropbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как загрузить с помощью кода c# файл на Dropbox, если проект у меня не ConsoleApp, а WinForms

Comment: Если дропбокс на компьютере установлен - достаточно просто записать файл в папку дропбокса. Ничем не отличается от записи файла в другое место компьютера. Если дропбокс может быть не установленным - необходимо использовать апи дропбокса - информация должне быть у них на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Например, использовать dropbox-api и их реализацию под [.net](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet). Для этого вам нужен токен, который можете получить [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) после авторизации.

Пример загрузки файла:

```
//DropBoxClient создает через конструктор, 
//в который передаете ваш токен new DropboxClient("Токен")
async Task Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file, string content)
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
    {
        var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
            folder + "/" + file,
            WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
            body: mem);
        Console.WriteLine("Saved {0}/{1} rev {2}", folder, file, updated.Rev);
    }
}
```

Более подробно можете почитать [тут](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial).